Power BI Date Table Slicer Returning Blank Visualizations
I am trying to create a date slicer with the date dimension table that will reduce records/count of records in a visualization based on the dates selected by the user. The date dimension table has an active relationship with a calculated date column called WorkItemDate that reflects the most recent update date related to a work item (additional details below in Point 4).
When I bring in the date dimension into a slicer, all visuals I have become blank.

I created a date dimension table based on the min/max dates generated from the union of non-null records in three date columns in my fact table (Created Date, Changed Date, Completed Date).

2.I made sure that all date fields have the same data type (date/time)/formatted in short date

Marked the new table as a date table.

Linked the dimension table to the fact table via a calculated date column called WorkItemDate that addresses the blanks in the Completed Date column (if there is no completed date, the calculated date table will reflect the Changed Date or Created Date value).


The date dimension table is currently generating values and has no null records.
Is there a step I am missing?
Code generating the date table:
DateTable = 

VAR MinDate = 
    MINX(
        FILTER(
            UNION(
                SELECTCOLUMNS('RDA', "Date", 'RDA'[CreatedDate]),
                SELECTCOLUMNS('RDA', "Date", 'RDA'[ChangedDate]),
                SELECTCOLUMNS('RDA', "Date", 'RDA'[CompletedDate])
            ),
            NOT(ISBLANK([Date]))  // Exclude null dates
        ),
        [Date]
    )

VAR MaxDate = 
    MAXX(
        FILTER(
            UNION(
                SELECTCOLUMNS('RDA', "Date", 'RDA'[CreatedDate]),
                SELECTCOLUMNS('RDA', "Date", 'RDA'[ChangedDate]),
                SELECTCOLUMNS('RDA', "Date", 'RDA'[CompletedDate])
            ),
            NOT(ISBLANK([Date]))  // Exclude null dates
        ),
        [Date]
    )


RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR(MinDate, MaxDate),
    "Year", YEAR([Date]),
    "Month Number", MONTH([Date]),
    "Month Name", FORMAT([Date], "MMMM"),
    "Quarter", "Q" & QUARTER([Date]),
    "Day of Week", WEEKDAY([Date], 1),
    "Day of Week Name", FORMAT([Date], "dddd"),
    "Week of Year", WEEKNUM([Date]),
    "Is Weekend", IF(WEEKDAY([Date], 1) >= 6, TRUE(), FALSE())

Code generating the new column:
WorkItemDate = 
IF (
    NOT(ISBLANK(RDA[CompletedDate])),
    RDA[CompletedDate],
    IF (
        NOT(ISBLANK(RDA[ChangedDate])),
        RDA[ChangedDate],
        RDA[CreatedDate]
    )
)


can you explain what you mean by "using the calculated column based on the user's selection"?

@RADO I have updated the post's first paragraph, I apologize about the confusing statement. I meant that the date dimension table would slice data based on the user's selected start/end date in the slicer and the slicers active relationship with calculated column WorkItemDate.
